# Calculate difference between current row and next available date value in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have get difference between the current Issue Reset and next stop time in `Postgres SQL`. I am not able to understand, how can i get this done using window functions. I tried `NEXT_VALUE` and `FIRST_VALUE`, but i am seeing examples for moving aggregates. I need a single query to get this.

I need to achieve difference between `'22/08/2020  11:29:00'` and `'17/08/2020  11:19:00'` which tells me duration of running time.

[image]

Comment: The structure of your table looks weird. Do you really have rows with a value in one column out of three?

Comment: yes, they can be null. since they are Issue Reset and stop time, which are problem is system running

Comment: What if you have two consecutive issues, then a stop time?

Comment: no, actually.. there is normal running and then a stoppage. Next operator reset (Issue TS) happens and normal running again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want the difference between each `stoptime` and the latest prior `issue`. If issues and stop times are properly interleaved, as you explained in the comments, then you can use window functions as follows:

```
select t.*, stop_time - max_issue as diff
from (
    select t.*, max(issue) over(order by issue) max_issue
    from mytable t
) t
where stop_time is not null
```